# Can I create a C# method inside a class and what type of method should I use?

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class Content {
      public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
      public string RowKey { get; set; }
}
```

The following View Model:

```
public class ContentViewModel
    {
        public ContentViewModel() { }
        public Content Content { get; set; }
        public bool UseRowKey { 
            get {
                return this.Content.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "05" ||
                       this.Content.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "06";
            }
        }
    }
```

I created the field "UseRowKey" in the ViewModel. However can I also create this as a method that's part of the class Content?

Comment: Not sure I get the problem. Yes you can define the method in the class or inherit from it. It depends on what they represent.

Comment: What would that method look like? I am used to Java and not so familiar with C#. Can I make a static (Instance) method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like

```
public class Content
{
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public bool UseRowKey
    {
        get
        {
            return PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "05" ||
                   PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "06";
        }
    }
}

public class ContentViewModel
{
    public ContentViewModel() { }
    public Content Content { get; set; }
    public bool UseRowKey
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Content.UseRowKey;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

To use it as a method, you can try

```
public class Content
{
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public bool UseRowKey()
    {
        return PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "05" ||
                   PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "06";

    }
}

public class ContentViewModel
{
    public ContentViewModel() { }
    public Content Content { get; set; }
    public bool UseRowKey
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Content.UseRowKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but this class is used to update data in a database and I believe that causes problems. Can I do this without using the get as a method?